# Is there a bilinear map on a non abelian group or non cyclic group?

Tags: pairings, group-theory

I've recently been studying a pairing map on cryptography.
In usual definition, a pairing map is always defined on the cyclic group G.
Is it possible to construct a bilinear map on a non-abelian group or non-cyclic group?

If it is possible, how can construct it? If not, why are they impossible?